# 3D building with Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, 3d, geowebcache

I am trying to add a 3D building layer with preferably as a tile (in GeoServer) to my Leaflet map. I have difficulty to find a tutorial for that. If you know a good link it would be great. I am open to any third party library like OSMBuilding.

I have found some questions like:
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560237/how-to-get-the-vector-tile-by-geoserver

and

[3D Map Visualization in Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149878/3d-map-visualization-in-geoserver)

but nothing that could help me to figure this out.

Comment: This might be wort looking into http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSMBuildings

Comment: Or https://www.npmjs.com/package/osmbuildings

Comment: Thank you @BillChappell, Unfortunately this does not contain any instruction/tutorial to show how to set data in a 3D db like (Postgis, citygml,)-> Geoserver-> leaflet

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet is only 2D library for creating interactive maps. It can not visualize in 3D. For 3D visualization you can try cesium.js or THREEjs as open source third party libraries.

Comment: I have looked at cesium.js and it isdocumented very well and really worth spending time on that. up-voted

Answer (score 2):

F4 maps can provide 3d tiles. see [here](http://demo.f4map.com/#camera.theta=0.9)

Comment: This was mind blowing, Neg point: not free, I love the cranes!